# How to make KDE applications look native in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, themes, kde-apps

Is there a way to make KDE applications (like digiKam) look native in GNOME?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you need the KDE's "System settings" application by installing  [systemsettings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemsettings) 
from the Software Center.

Search the dash for System settings and launch it .
Then make the following changes:

- under Style → Applications → Widget style, select GTK+
- under Colors, select the colours to match your GTK theme or download the [Ambiance colour scheme](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1682563)  .
- under Icons → Theme, select the icon theme you are using in GTK apps
- under Fonts select "Ubuntu", size 11

Comment: Shouldn't be that configuration default in ubuntu? It would look much better, and less uncompatible. Any reason why it's not default?

Comment: @rafalcieslak feel free to [ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) a new question :)

Comment: It's probably better to suggest installing the QT-4 configurator instead of the KDE Systemsettings manager - since the QT configurator does the same job for this case and has less dependencies.

Comment: @Alaukik: relax dude... and actually I think you're wrong cause I've used QT's configurator in the past for the same purpose.

Comment: The package @RolandiXor suggests is called `qt4-qtconfig`.

Comment: The menus described in this answer do not exist in the `systemsettings` applications. Moreover, this application is well known to have no impact on the KDE applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not work. The app is just blank and broken in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 9):

Currently using ***Ubuntu 22.04***. The following solution is applied to my system and has been tested on `fontmatrix`, that is QT5 app.

You can apply QT styles that recreate GTK look and feel via the packages `qt5-style-kvantum` (theme manager) and `qt5-style-kvantum-themes` (collection of styles). To install them, run the command:

`sudo apt install qt5-style-kvantum qt5-style-kvantum-themes`

Then, you need to tell to your system to use `kvantum` style for QT5 apps. This is performed by setting the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` variable in your `.profile` file.

You have two alternative ways.

*Alternative 1*

- run `echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> $HOME/.profile`

*Alternative 2:*

- open the file with `gedit $HOME/.profile`
- add the line (if not present) `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum`
- save the file.

After changing the `.profile` file, you have to logout from your account and login, then it will be sourced automatically.

Now, open the Kvantum Manager app from the app-grid menu:

- Click on the submenu "Change/Delete Theme"
- Select "KvYaru" from "Select Menu".
- Click "Use this theme" button.

[image: Kvantum Manager]

This is the way to activate a style that resembles the default Ubuntu theme, called Yaru. By default, a lots of themes are installed, so you can choose what you prefer.

The Kvantum project is available at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum).

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04, what worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-style-plugins
```

This is taken from the [ArchLinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications). It also recommends setting the `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` environment variable, but I did not need that.