# Advanced System Monitor/Task Manager?

Tags: software-recommendation, system-monitor, process-priority

When using kubuntu I noticed that the standard task manager/system monitor was a bit more capable than `gnome-system-monitor`, is there a more advanced system/task monitor for ubuntu that is based on gnome opposed to KDE?

Specifically the features from the Kubuntu task manager that I am looking for are the ability to control the I/O priority of individual processes (not just their `nice`), and the ability to control the I/O scheduling algorithm ( round-robin, FIFO, etc).

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use KDE apps in Gnome, [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome/24786#24786) to make them look native.

KDE System Guard ([click to install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/ksysguard))

[image]

> KSysGuard is designed to make simple process control available to a user without needing to do any special setup - the defaults are usually perfectly adequate. There are two worksheets - the System Load page, pictured above, and the Process Table.