# Is there an user activity monitor/alarm?

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

There once was a tool called Active Work Tracker for Windows from Brigsoft.

What it basically did was to monitor user activity, sound alarm after a predefined period (say 60 minutes), wait another predefined time (say 5 minutes) when user was supposed to take a break (which was recognized as lack of activity), and repeat the whole procedure.

In addition, it recorded the total time user spends on his computer and presented nice charts.

I wonder whether there is a similar application for Ubuntu?

You can see more detailed description of Active Work Tracker at http://www.abstime.com/bsactivity/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**RSIBreak**](http://www.rsibreak.org/). ([Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/rsibreak))

[image]

[image]

> Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI) is an illness which can occur as a result of continuous work with a mouse and keyboard. The risk of suffering injury increases the longer users work without breaks. RSIBreak simply offers reminders to take a break now and then.
>
> After the start it will show up in your system tray and will monitor your activity. Whenever it detects that you have been active for a certain amount of time (configurable) it will prompt you for a break. It has some settings so if you walk away from your keyboard, it can reset the timers, so you will not be bothered with a break right after you return from that coffee break.
>
> You can setup RSIBreak to popup a tiny notification popup to remind you to take a break, but you can also configure it to black out your screen so you can not continue working. All to your liking.

Since this is a kde app you should [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome/24786#24786) to make it look native in gnome

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I have just installed it and started testing.

At first glance it is what I've been looking for :)

Comment: Is there a GNOME equivalent?  I'd rather not load up the KDE libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a keyboard lock (typing break) in *System->Preferences->Keyboard*:

[image]

However with this settings the total time a user worked without a break are neither logged nor displayed.

Comment: Interesting :) I've just configured 5 mins breaks after 60 mins and started testing.

Comment: I've tested it and it works fine. I'd like to "accept" both answers, but seems it is not possible at askubuntu :(

Comment: @mjaniec: that's perfectly fine. I personally would have accepted @scottl's answer too :)

Comment: I finally decided to use this system tool. It's the easiest and pretty strict in enforcement :)

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions include Workrave (Gnome/GTK+, so no need for special styling) and Xwrits (X-libraries only, but interface is weaker IMO).

This article compares all three:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9114