# How to change the value of ~

Tags: command-line, home-directory

by default `~` is given the value of `/home/username/`

i.e. If I use the command `cd ~` it goes to the directory `/home/username/`

How to change the value of it to some other file such as /home/username/filename?

I do know that this can be dangerous, I am working on a CTF though, so it is fine.

Comment: Bad idea, that will break stuff. If you want: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103666/is-it-possible-to-redefine-the-tilde-home-directory

Comment: Do you want to move your user home directory to another location? Otherwise I don't see what the purpose of your endeavour would be. You could set the environment variable `HOME` to something else, but that will break stuff… badly.

Comment: I am aware of it I just need the command :) I won't use it to break any thing I am working on a CTF :)

Comment: What does `CTF` stand for?

Comment: @EricWilson From OP's comment on Tim's post, I guess it is "Capture the Flag". Perhaps OP is participating in some Unix golf contest.

Comment: Ya CTF means Capture the flag, I am participating in a Security contest :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The tilde (~) is interpreted by your shell, as a short form of `$HOME`.
>
> Try the following commands:
>
> ```
> echo ~
> HOME=foo
> echo ~
> ```
>
> This should first print your real home directory and afterwards "foo", as you set $HOME` to that.
>
> The default value of `$HOME` comes from you system configuration. Use `getent passwd` to list all known users and their home directories. Depending on your system configuration those entries might come from `/etc/passwd` or any remote directory service.
>
> If you only want to temporarily redefine your home directory, just set another `$HOME`.
>
> If you permanently want to change it you have to change the passwd entry, e.g. by manually editing `/etc/passwd`.

[Taken from this U&L question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103666/is-it-possible-to-redefine-the-tilde-home-directory)

Comment: Tq I have got the flag in ctf :) from the link you suggested me is unix stack exchange form :) which is same as the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the `$HOME` variable , because tilde (`~`) is a short form of `$HOME`, or change your user's home directory in `/etc/passwd` but that's not recommended.

Why you don't try to make and **alias** for `cd /home/username/filename` like this:

```
alias documents='cd ~/Documents'
```

Now when you type `documents` it will change to `/home/user/Documents`

More info in [`man alias`](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html).

To make that alias permanent, [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias).

Comment: Where would you put the alias? Because if I put it in `/`, it only works (`cd aliasname`) when I am there, etc. I can't put it everywhere.

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying, can you explain it in more detail

Comment: In your .bashrc file in /home/username

Comment: Can you [edit] it to explain how to do this? To me an alias is a symbolic link (made with the `ln` command.

Comment: you can search @Tim i posted alias man page !!!

Comment: Then this comment applies: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: at least i didn't copy and paste .

Comment: I referenced, and I gave a good answer - http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11720/what-to-do-if-the-good-answer-is-in-another-question