# Is there any software solution for office ergonomics?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any kind of software that is lightweight, configurable in a LAN environment for office ergonomics.

Office ergonomics is about improving productivity by and reducing complaints from workers and reducing lost work time incidents.

Answer (score 15):

### [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/)

[image: screeshot]

[image: screeshot]

> Workrave is a program that assists in the recovery and prevention of Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI). The program frequently alerts you to take micro-pauses, rest breaks and restricts you to your daily limit. Please refer to the feature comparison for a complete list of features, and how the program performs with respect to other programs on the market. The program runs on GNU/Linux and Microsoft Windows.

### [RSIBreak](http://www.rsibreak.org/)

> Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI) is an illness which can occur as a result of continuous work with a mouse and keyboard. The risk of suffering injury increases the longer users work without breaks. RSIBreak simply offers reminders to take a break now and then.
>
> After the start it will show up in your system tray and will monitor your activity. Whenever it detects that you have been active for a certain amount of time (configurable) it will prompt you for a break. It has some settings so if you walk away from your keyboard, it can reset the timers, so you will not be bothered with a break right after you return from that coffee break.
>
> You can setup RSIBreak to popup a tiny notification popup to remind you to take a break, but you can also configure it to black out your screen so you can not continue working. All to your liking.

Since this is a KDE app you should [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome/24786#24786) to make it look native in GNOME.

Comment: I'm going to try these two application...thanks

Comment: sadly, workrave has been removed from the oneiric repositories.

Comment: I think the RSIBreak link is not right, I found this one instead: [https://kde.org/applications/utilities/org.kde.rsibreak](https://kde.org/applications/utilities/org.kde.rsibreak)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [xwrits](http://www.lcdf.org/xwrits) is another option.

> Xwrits reminds you to take wrist breaks, which will hopefully help you prevent repetitive stress injury. It pops up an X window when you should rest; you click on that window, then take a break.