# How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO using Windows?

Tags: dvd, iso, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 ISO image but I am not sure how to burn it. Can I burn it by right clicking and selecting burn with Nero option or do I need any special software. I am using Windows 7 32bit.

It would be nice of you if you can give me the step by step instruction!