# iso image is not getting burned properly!

Tags: 12.04, dvd, iso, cd, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

i tried burning the ubuntu 12.04 iso image in many cd's and dvd's but the iso file does not get expanded. it shows only the iso file in it and some cd's dont show up anything. i tried burning with infrarecorder and burn windows image option by right clicking. how do i burn the file now?iam using windows 7 32bit and i also have nero (if its of any use). please help me, iam in a big trouble!

Comment: I would recommend using the program ImgBurn. Whenever I used Windows, this program always did the trick for me.

Comment: you need to make yourself clear. what do you mean by *some cd's dont show up anything*? are you saying that this machine can't show other cd's either? what do you mean by *it shows only the iso file in it*? are you saying that it shows the ISO file when you try to check the contents of the CD after burning?

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/a/126069/6005

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are selecting "Burn image to disk" option rather than  "burn file to disk"?

Anyways, if you have nero, you can burn an existing image from there. just open **nero >> extra >> burn image to disk** [this order might change depending upon the nero versio you are using]

After doing that, you should be able to see the contents of the image in the nero window.
Just burn the disk and tell me if all goes right.

Cheers

Comment: should i do this in a blank cd or n the cd that i have already tried burning?

Comment: @harikrishnan do that in a **new blank cd** and you should have no problems if every thing goes fine. And yes, **select the lowest possible burn speed after clicking _burn_ to prvent loss of data**

Answer (score 1):

Expanded? You're saying that you see the ISO file on your burned disc instead of the contents of the ISO file? If that is the case, you used the wrong burn option. Burn the ISO file as an image, *do not* burn a data CD or DVD containing just the ISO file.

Comment: but then why did it not work with infrarecorder. i burned it like this in infrarecorder: action - burn image