# Burning Ubuntu 12.04 in Windows

Tags: installation, live-cd, burning

I have Windows 7, and when I attempt to download Ubuntu from the official site, it is indicated that I will get an .iso file, which you burn to the disk.

But, i did not get an .iso file after I downloaded it.

So, should I just copy the downloaded data to the CD-R?

Comment: You say you didn't get the .iso? Then what did you get when you downloaded it?

Comment: you perhaps should clarify what you downloaded - and what the filename you see in file-manager.  You should also do a md5sum to ensure the integrity of the file you downloaded.

Comment: @fossfreedom Windows does not show file extensions.

Comment: you can enable that in folder options

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen but that is not on by default, and the Op may not have that on or know how to set that.

Comment: It's good to see someone who found Windows too complicated and is making the move to Linux.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How burn or mount an ISO file?](http://askubuntu.com/q/62518/22949) (in particular, see [LnxSlck's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/172799/22949))

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what link you used, on what browser? You can try using this link, which wil download a .iso file to your hard disk, which you may open to use with the CD burner application on your system. You may try using the link http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso and then double-clicking on the file you have downloaded once it finishes. If you need help downloading, press <kbd>F1</kbd> and consult your browser help. ALso, if you want the AMD64 version, I can give you a link for that.

Edit:You may try right-clicking on the file you do have and selecting Open With, and selecting the Windows Disc burning utility or something like that.