# Ubuntu's .iso is read as .rar on Windows. Should I install it on a USB Drive assuming it's an ISO?

Tags: installation, usb, iso, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

I'm trying to make an install with a USB Drive with ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.

However, it is showing on Windows Vista 32bit as a winrar file.

Do I need to extract this using `WinRAR`, before I continue, or do I simply use the pendrive usb installer without extracting?