# How to copy an Ubuntu ISO file to CD-R in Windows 8?

Tags: installation, windows-8, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

I need to copy the iso file for Ubuntu 12.04 to a CD-R in Win8. How do I do so?