# Can ubuntu backup my Windows 7 files?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have a problem with Windows 7. All efforts to fix it have failed. Someone suggested I install Ubuntu and backup my Windows files. Are there instructions available somewhere?

Comment: Do you want to have Ubuntu and Windows or do backup your files and install **only Ubuntu**?

Comment: Lucio, at this time I just wanted to recover my data files using a bootable CD as suggested by Sergey. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that what they meant was "boot from Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB to be able to access Windows 7 files from the live session". *Installing* Ubuntu on the hard drive is likely to destroy your files forever, especially if you don't know what to do.

You need to somehow [make a bootable Ubuntu CD/USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and boot from that. Then you'll be able to access your Windows filesystem and backup your files (to an external HDD, for example).

Comment: Sergey, I made a bootable CD and I have booted from that. I am in the process of going through my Windows files and copying the data files to a USB memory stick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [burn it into a CD/DVD](https://askubuntu.com/q/62518/62483) or [into a USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/a/192723/62483).

Now from the Live version you can see the files and save them. Backup this files using DVDs or any external device.