# How do you run a ISO file?

Tags: iso

Im trying to figure out on how to run an iso rather than mounting it but I have tried checking other sources but I either don't get what it means or it's the opposite. Help on this would be awesome.

Comment: What do you mean by "run" an ISO? ISO's are not executable files...

Comment: Umm by opening an ISO. Is it possible?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You should just add a comment, and then flag the most ;-) There is a special duplicate flag reason.

Comment: @Fauksy No, you don't open ISO's. Maybe if you explained what you are trying to do we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Rightclick->openwith->archive manager

Answer (score 1):

"run an ISO rather than mounting" -- there is no such thing. An ISO is a disk image representing a CD-ROM, and this determines what you can do with it: mount it or burn it to a physical CD (and then typically use that CD to boot).

See: [How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)