# Unable to burn Ubuntu to DVD

Tags: windows-8, 14.04, system-installation, system

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and when I click on `This PC` -> `Downloads`, the file is listed as a `Winrar zip file` as `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`.  However, when I click on this file, I get this error message :

```
C:\Users\Windows 8\Downloads\ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso. The archive is either in unknown format or damaged.
```

I am running Windows 8.1 Update but am not very computer literate.  Can someone please advise me exactly what I should do to install the operating system on a second 500 GB hard that I have installed internally in my computer so that whenever I want to use Ubuntu, all I have to do is to disconnect my primary drive with Windows 8.1 and then connect the cables to the second hard drive.  That way, I suppose Ubuntu will boot.

When I right click on the downloaded file and then choose `Open With`, I do not see the option `Windows Disc Image Burner`.  The only options are `Windows Explorer`, `WinRar archiver` and `Choose Default Program`.  But when I choose this option, the only other options are `Adobe Reader`, `Internet Explorer`, `Microsoft Office` etc.   How then do I install Ubuntu?  I would appreciate all responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How burn or mount an ISO file?](http://askubuntu.com/q/62518/22949) (has Windows answers)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some software like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com).

However, there is an easier method if you have a USB drive, by using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to copy the ISO to USB.

Here is what you should do (based on a screenshot from Rufus webpage):

[image]

- Select your device (USB stick) from the first combobox
- click the button (1) and select the `ISO` from `Downloads`
- Click `Start` (2)
- Wait for it to finish
- Restart PC and boot from USB (you should keep pressing a key when you see the POST screen)
- If you can't read this [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is insert a blank dvd in your dvd burner, right click on the iso and then click 'burn disc image'.  You don't need to download any burning software.  See here:

http://theunlockr.com/2013/04/25/how-to-burn-iso-files-in-windows-8/