# How to make an Ubuntu down load bootable

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have dual boot Ubuntu/windows.  I want to kill windows and have one large partition for Ubuntu.  I saved the Ubuntu down load to DVD.  I had to. Not enough room on my drive.  I tried to restart and boot off the DVD.  Computer ignored it and took me to the boot menu. What I downloaded is called ubuntu-14.04.0-desktop-amd64.iso.  there is a file called iso linux but I haven't extracted anything.  Not enough room on my drive.  I just want to do a fresh install, getting rid of the Windows partition.

Comment: When you say "saved .. to DVD", did you burn the image to a DVD or burn the ISO as a file to a DVD? What are the contents of the DVD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How burn or mount an ISO file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file)

Answer (score 0):

Burn the image to disk, then when you boot to DVD drive, just simply follow the instructions to wipe the hard drive and install Ubuntu.

Comment: I did burn the image to disk.  Then I restarted my computer with the DVD in the drive.  It went right past that to my dual boot log in screen without launching what was on the DVD