# I am confused, I download ubuntu into my windows 8 laptop and cannot get ubuntu to start,

Tags: boot

I have downloaded Ubuntu from this site to my Toshiba 64 bit, windows 8 laptop. It's burned onto a dvd, moved from the downloads onto the desktop and is in the 'home-icon' start prompt, but no prompt comes up to start the boot. Do I have to remove Ubuntu from the downloads, desktop and start position, and boot the computer and  upload Ubuntu from the DVD?

Comment: Sounds like you burned the iso to the disk as a file not an image.  That's just what I see though.  Might want to look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-to-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file/126069#126069

Comment: Please advise the flavor and version of Ubuntu every time you pose a question here. Click on the `edit` link above and to the left to update your query.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to reboot the computer and boot into Ubuntu from the DVD.  See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Using_your_LiveCD

The Live-DVD will let you try Ubuntu directly from the DVD and will provide an icon with which Ubuntu can be installed on your computer.