# How do I burn a multi-track .img image to a CD-R or CD-RW?

Tags: iso, cd, convert

I have an .img file sizing about 600 MiB. When I wanted to burn this file to a CD (not a DVD), I could not find any program capable of doing so. I tried K3b, Brasero, and AcetoneISO. Nothing was able to burn the .img file.

Then i tried to convert it to an .iso with AcetoneISO, but it said i would lose important tracks (multitrack disc). The outcome was a file of 160 MiB or so, so I figured this was no solution either.

I do not want to write the .img image to a  USB stick, but only burn it to a CD. In the case that such an .img image is from a bootable
CD, I cannot simply dump its contents to a folder by copying and then burn that folder to the CD-R after mounting it. Doing that would fail to produce a bootable CD.

Is there any program in Ubuntu's repositories that can do this? Is there another way to convert the file?

This is not a duplicate of [How to burn or mount an ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62518/how-to-burn-or-mount-an-iso-file) because I am asking how to burn an .img image to CD-R or CD-RW and *not* an .iso. I am not able to find any CD-R software for burning .img image files to a disc.

**The reason this is *not* a duplicate** is that I am asking for a method for  how to burn an .img (not an .iso, nor a .bin/.cue) image to a CD-R in Linux. The linked question does not appear to answer this. I am unable to find any burner in the repos in Xubuntu that does this. AcetoneISO does *mount* the image, but that is not what I want, since **it is a multi-track .img** (all tracks in one .img file). I also want to burn it to a CD-R so that it remains bootable. K3b and other burners do not accept any .img file for burning.

Converting it to an .iso with AcetoneISO or any other program **makes it lose the additional tracks beyond track 1** and possibly also to lose the bootable aspect.

Comment: no i updated the question

Comment: There should be no difference between burning a real .iso and some other
kind of image file. Try:

xorriso -as cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 blank=as_needed your_image_file.whatever

(With your file name instead of "your_image_file.whatever".)

Comment: Have you tried directly burning the .img file to CD-RW? What was the result?

Comment: trying to burn it with k3d - image not recognised or something like it as with all other burners. renaming it to iso or bin does not fix this - still the same error message because no burn applications i can find actually CAN burn a .IMG file. the disks app (gnome) can make a .IMG of a cd-r but not burn it. having a method to convert the multitrack .IMG file to a multitrack BIN/CUE would also solve the problem i guess since k3b can burn those. cd-rw gives the same result by the way.